# My app is not building debug console says Could not build the application for the simulator

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code, flutter

This is the output when trying to build the basic application when creating a new file. Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone XR in debug mode...
Xcode build done.
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
While building module 'Flutter' imported from /Users/davywavy/Desktop/Flutter Projects/premium/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h:8:
In file included from :1:
In file included from /Users/davywavy/Desktop/Flutter Projects/premium/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/Flutter.h:37:
In file included from /Users/davywavy/Desktop/Flutter Projects/premium/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:11:
/Users/davywavy/Desktop/Flutter Projects/premium/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterPlugin.h:140:58: warning: this block declaration is not a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
completionHandler:(nonnull void (^)())completionHandler;
^
void
1 warning generated.
1 warning generated.
ld: framework not found Flutter
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build description
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone XR.
Exited (sigterm)

I have tried fixing my path flutter upgrade, flutter doctor -v everything looks right.

Comment: Yes I have tried the things suggested in similar posts.

Answer (score -1):

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone XR in debug mode...
Xcode build done.
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
error: /Users/davywavy/Desktop/Flutter Projects/premium/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig: unable to open file (in project "Runner") (in target 'Runner')
error: /Users/davywavy/Desktop/Flutter Projects/premium/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig: unable to open file (in project "Runner") (in target 'Runner')
error: /Users/davywavy/Desktop/Flutter Projects/premium/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig: unable to open file (in project "Runner") (in target 'Runner')
error: /Users/davywavy/Desktop/Flutter Projects/premium/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig: unable to open file (in project "Runner") (in target 'Runner')
error: /Users/davywavy/Desktop/Flutter Projects/premium/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig: unable to open file (in project "Runner") (in target 'Runner')
error: /Users/davywavy/Desktop/Flutter Projects/premium/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig: unable to open file (in project "Runner") (in target 'Runner')
note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Using build description from disk
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone XR.
Exited (sigterm)

new output